# I can't run my app in emulator after I renamed the folder of the project

Tags: android, android-studio

I almost finished my app so I decided to rename the folder's project with a specific name. Before this I've done a backup just in case but now when I run the app in emulator I got this error for both of them as shown here:

[image]

This only happens when I execute the app with `Instant Run` otherwise it will work (in emulator). The fun part is that I've tested this issue on 2 actual devices, on *LG Optimus L7 2* and *Samsung Galaxy A3*. With `Instant Run` enabled it worked only on the first phone and with `Instant Run` disabled it worked on both of them.

In the image that I've posted I've shown a specific path (`E:\backup\AndroidGame\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk`)

> Please note that I moved the folder "backup" into another disk because I thought it might interfer with the original folder of the project. So the path shown in the image does not exists anymore in local disk E. Only the folder named `AndroidGame` which I opened with Android Studio. This is not the first time I changed the name of the folder's project but then it worked without any problem.

**The app is like finished so i shouldn't worry about this? Will it work after exporting the project to an apk?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not change your Folder Name, because when you build new APK then App can not find out folder for output files.

**Follow this Trick:**

**1. Close android studio**

**2. Change project root directory name**

**3. Open android studio**

**4. Open the project(not from local history but by browsing to it)**

Comment: At that time i didn't know that, but like 2 weeks ago i did the same thing and then it worked... Ok I'll try, thanks!

Comment: close your current Project & then remove from recent Projects

Comment: Import your Project in Android Studio then clear your project. it should might be can help you.

Answer (score 5):

In order to replicate the error, i've changed the name of the projects folder like this:

from `..projectsFolder/myAndroidAppFolder/`
to `..projectsFolderNew/myAndroidAppFoder/`

I got the same error and order to fix it I followed this steps:

`1. File>Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment>Instant Run>Disable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy(default enabled)`

`2. Build>Clean Project`

`3. Build>Rebuild Project`

`4. Run 'app' (Shift+F10)`

`5. File>Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment>Instant Run>Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy`

`6. Stop (Ctrl+F2)`

`7. Run 'app' (Shift+F10)`

I had four Android apps in that folder and it worked for all of them. Hope it will work for you too.

Comment: Cheers for this! I had to turn this off and on to get my Kotlin project deploying to my phone. I think Instant Run was only introduced in March 2017, so it might not have affected the original poster.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer thnx man so much! I had to reInstall my OSX and got into this issue but now its resolved

Answer (score 1):

Removing the build directories under MyApplication and app directories worked for me. I just moved my sample application to a different location and start having the same issue.

Essentially Rebuild would also do but I didn't tried to be honest.